# SQL Query to get details from vertical format in horizontal format

Tags: sql-server

Hi
I have created a table.

--------------|---------------|
cust1         | cust2        |
--------------|---------------|
customer  | C1             |
account     | A1             |
transaction| T1             |
transaction| T2             |
transaction| T3             |
account     | A2             |
transaction| T11           |
transaction| T12           |
transaction| T13           |
customer   | C2            |
account     | A1             |
transaction| T111         |
transaction| T112         |
transaction| T113         |
account     | A2             |
transaction| T1111        |
transaction| T1112        |
transaction| T1113        |
--------------|---------------|

Please help me to build SQL Query to get result in below format:

----------------------|-------------------|---------------------|
customer            | account          | transaction       |
----------------------|-------------------|---------------------|
C1                       | A1                  | T1                     |
C1                       | A1                  | T2                     |
C1                       | A1                  | T3                     |
C1                       | A2                  | T11                   |
C1                       | A2                  | T12                   |
C1                       | A2                  | T13                   |
C2                       | A1                  | T111                 |
C2                       | A1                  | T112                 |
C2                       | A1                  | T113                 |
C2                       | A2                  | T1111               |
C2                       | A2                  | T1112               |
C2                       | A2                  | T1113               |
----------------------|-------------------|---------------------|

Thanks

Comment: There's a serious problem with your database design. Fix that before trying to get the result. You should have columns customer, account and transaction in the table.

Comment: this is challenge given by my colleague :) however data is in vertical format. I have tried to use case but it gives NULL in every Row.

Comment: If it's a challenge given to you, doesn't that mean that you should be solving it instead of us?

Comment: @JamesZ: I have tried all possible way but SQL is not my specialization as I am VBA Developer hence trying to get some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have some kind of order for your data, so this is how you can do it if you add for example an identity field to the table called id to keep track of the order of the data:

```
select c.cust2, a.cust2, t.cust2
from table1 t
outer apply (
  select top 1 cust2, id from table1 t1
  where t1.id < t.id and cust1 = 'customer' 
  order by id desc
) c
outer apply (
  select top 1 cust2, id from table1 t1
  where t1.id < t.id and cust1 = 'account' 
  order by id desc
) a
where cust1 = 'transaction'
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a9b5/1)

Edit: This will work without changes to the table, but can break at any time.

```
;with Table1 as (
  select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id,*
  from table2                            
)

select c.cust2, a.cust2, t.cust2
from table1 t
outer apply (
  select top 1 cust2, id from table1 t1
  where t1.id < t.id and cust1 = 'customer' 
  order by id desc
) c
outer apply (
  select top 1 cust2, id from table1 t1
  where t1.id < t.id and cust1 = 'account' 
  order by id desc
) a
where cust1 = 'transaction'
```

Comment: Is there way to use same table like we have, without altering it get the output?

Comment: @VinayakIsave Tables do not have an order, so you can't assume having order without actually having one. Your question assumes that the data is in order (customer & account before transaction). If you try to do it without having a defined order, you can get wrong results.

Comment: I have tried the below query which gives NULL in every row..there must be something to get output without altering table structure.

select
case when cust1 = 'customer' then cust2 end as 'customer',
 case when cust1 = 'account' then cust2 end as 'account', 
 case when cust1 = 'transaction' then cust2 end as 'transaction'
from test

Comment: @VinayakIsave That will never work because that assumes your data is in the same row. I added an example how to do this without changes to the table. But you should really understand that SQL Server does not have any kind of order based on the insert sequence, so your data can break at any time.

Comment: thanks alot James..U showed two ways of doing it...Thanks again..
really appretiate your help :)